# Assigning style/class to labels of checkboxes in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a a simple group of checkboxes generated by cakePHP's form

```
echo $form->input('Interest.interest_id', array('label' => __l('Interests'), 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

There's a main Label called Interests and then a label for every checkbox generated, how do I apply a seperate class style to the labels of the checkboxes?

SNIPPET

```
<label for="InterestInterestId">Interests</label>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="data[Interest][interest_id]">
<div class="checkbox">
<input id="InterestInterestId8" type="checkbox" value="8" name="data[Interest][interest_id][]">
<label for="InterestInterestId8">Label of Checkbox</label>
</div>
```

My main objective is to have the checkbox display nicely inline infront of the label, but due to other styling it's not displaying like that in default

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the HTML for both kinds of labels?

Comment: @Allen - I've added a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you can distinguish your styling for the checkbox label as:

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline;
}
.checkbox label {
    display: inline;
}
```

That worked for me but I don't know what CSS you have for the other label that this label may be inheriting.  Here is the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/XBXVs/

Comment: And how would I go about adding inline styles?

Comment: I realized that the elements are inline by default =)  You can use "float" as well.

Comment: Yes, they are but the page uses styles that say display:block; which causes the problem, I unfortunately can't remove the block so I need to overwrite it

Comment: If you can include more of the parent elements in the CSS selector, you may be able to override the inherited styling.  Can you post the css snippet that does the "block"?

Comment: I need to overwrite this
form.normal div.login-left-block div.input label, div.login-right-block form.normal div.input label {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

Comment: I've used your suggestion as in your answer, and this worked fine.Thanks Liu